# how to show search results page in an overlay

Tags: java, javascript, aem

I need to display search results page in an overlay.
For that I have created one div:

```
  <div class="overlaybox" id="overlaybox" style="display:none">
      <sling:include path="/content/myapp/searchpage.html" />     
  </div>
```

I'm able to show the search page in overlay using the above code (without appending any query string to the path). However,
now when I hit search, I need to append the query entered in the search as request parameter to this searchpage.html, then only search results will be populated in the search page. For now, in the above code, no request parameter is passed, so it is showing no results.
So I tried with the below code:

```
    String keyword="games"
    String path="/content/myapp/searchpage.html?q="+keyword;
```

and used that path in the sling:include as follows

```
    <div class="overlaybox" id="overlaybox" style="display:none">
        <sling:include path="<%=path%>" />     
    </div>
```

However, that did not work. Can anyone tell me how we can add the **query string** to the path?

Comment: Please attach you code, we can't help you without code.

Comment: It's a good idea to proofread the questions that you post to make sure that everything is legible.  Remember to indent your code fragments with four spaces.  An easy-to-read question is one that is more likely to be answered.

Comment: ya sure,I find problem in aligning the code,i will try to post easy to read questions in future,thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sling:include the searchpage, your page component rendering script (presumably searchpage.jsp) will be executed.  Thus, you should be able to read the query parameter from that script using standard code, ie:

```
String keyword = slingRequest.getParameter("q");
```

If the parameter your passing isn't actually in the URL query string, but needs to be hardcoded, perhaps you could use a selector:

```
<sling:include path="/content/myapp/searchpage.html" addSelectors="games">
...
String keyword = slingRequest.getRequestPathInfo().getSelectorsString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Shsteimer,with this I came to know that this is the way of sending the query string parameters using a sling include